# Compatibility of Ubuntu 20.04 for i5 4th gen laptop processor

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, intel, nvidia-geforce

I have a Lenovo laptop with Intel Core i5 4200M, Nvidia GeForce GT 740M, and 4 GB of RAM. Can I install Ubuntu 20.04 and use it smoothly? or should I install Xubuntu? I will mainly use it for browsing and office work and some light gaming though

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu would work on your computer, but may be your graphic card would make it laggy, better to use Xubuntu, is like Ubuntu, but only with XFCE, (You can install Ubuntu and if the OS is laggy, do `sudo apt install xfce-desktop`)